# Is there a built-in option to force websites to use Dark Mode in all major browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, microsoft-edge, dark-mode

Google Chrome can do so using `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark`:

[image: Google Chrome's force dark mode flag]

Do other major browsers (like Edge/Firefox/Safari) have a similar **built-in** flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edge has exactly the same flag as Chrome:
`edge://flags/#enable-force-dark`

[image: Edge's forced dark mode flag]

Comment: @LWC Don't know about Safari. I think (not 100% sure) for Firefox an addon is required

Comment: firefox>>>>>>https://itsfoss.com/firefox-dark-mode/

Comment: @Moab - this article just explains to download an addon like Reddy suggested.